# Invalid localdate when it created

Tags: java, java-time

With java 8

i was thinking to get 31 march 2016 with this line of code

```
System.out.println(LocalDate.now().withDayOfMonth(31).withMonth(3).withYear(2016));
```

i get
Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid date 'APRIL 31'

Comment: Reorder the `withMonth` with the `withDayOfMonth`. You're currently trying to set the 31st day for this month, which is April. April doesn't have 31 days. You don't need to use this method for setting a date, use the `LocalDate` constructor instead.

Comment: `LocalDate` [`of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#of-int-int-int-) static factory but it is the same point :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comments said, having run this in April of 2016, you were attempting to change the date to 31 which does not exist in the current month of April. So change the month to March before setting the day-of-month.

Even better, use the static [`of`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#of-int-int-int-) method.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2016 , 3 , 31 );
```

Or use an [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) constant [`Month.MARCH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#MARCH).

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2016 , Month.MARCH , 31 );
```